# Having trouble understanding immutable, mutable, scope in python functions

Tags: python, scope, immutability, mutable

See my code in python 3.4. I can get around it fine. It bugs me a little. I'm guessing it's something to do with foo2 resetting a rather than treating it as list 1.

```
def foo1(a):
    a.append(3) ### add element 3 to end of list
    return()

def foo2(a):
    a=a+[3] #### add element 3 to end of list
    return()

list1=[1,2]
foo1(list1)
print(list1) ### shows [1,2,3]

list1=[1,2]
foo2(list1)
print(list1) #### shows [1,2]
```

Comment: Unrelated to this: there is no reason to use `return()` if you do not return anything, and return is not a function. Instead you return an empty tuple - which certainly is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In `foo2` you do not mutate the original list referred to by a - instead, you create a new list from `list1` and `[3]`, and bind the result which is a new list to the *local* name `a`. So `list1` is not changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between append and +=

```
>>> a = []
>>> id(a)
11814312
>>> a.append("hello")
>>> id(a)
11814312

>>> b = []
>>> id(b)
11828720
>>> c = b + ["hello"]
>>> id(c)
11833752
>>> b += ["hello"]
>>> id(b)
11828720
```

As you can see, append and += have the same result; they add the item to the list, without producing a new list. Using + adds the two lists and produces a new list.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're using a method that modifies `a` in-place. In the second example, you're making a new `a` that replaces the old `a` but without modifying the old `a` - that's usually what happens when you use the `=` to assign a new value. One exception is when you use slicing notation on the left-hand side: `a[:] = a + [3]` would work as your first example did.

Comment: Thank you  - going to try the slicing notation